# How to sort double dictionary ? (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm beginner programing. 
I'm struggling to make code which returns game result order depending on the number of wins and games. For example,

```
teams = {
'Arsenal FC': {
    'name': 'Arsenal FC',
    'wins': 4,
    'games_played': 15,
},
'Chelsea FC': {
    'name': 'Chelsea FC',
    'wins': 6,
    'games_played': 16,
},
'Madrid Real': {
    'name': 'Madrid Real',
    'wins': 4,
    'games_played': 11,
}
}
```

This case, I want to return above like this list :

```
[
 {
 'Chelsea FC': {
    'name': 'Chelsea FC',
    'wins': 6,
    'games_played': 16,
 },
 'Madrid Real': {
    'name': 'Madrid Real',
    'wins': 4,
    'games_played': 11,
 },
'Arsenal FC': {
    'name': 'Arsenal FC',
    'wins': 4,
    'games_played': 15,
 }
]
```

The team won the most should be top. If the number of wins was equal to another team, the team have less games_played should come up.
I'm sorry my bad English skills. If you couldn't understand what I aim, please ask.
It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a "sort key" to `sorted()`:

```
>>> sorted(teams.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1]["wins"], x[1]["games_played"]))
[('Chelsea FC', {'games_played': 16, 'name': 'Chelsea FC', 'wins': 6}),
 ('Madrid Real', {'games_played': 11, 'name': 'Madrid Real', 'wins': 4}),
 ('Arsenal FC', {'games_played': 15, 'name': 'Arsenal FC', 'wins': 4})]
```

To get the exact dictionary structure in your example, you can do

```
>>> [{k:v} for k,v in sorted(teams.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1]["wins"], x[1]["games_played"]))]
[{'Chelsea FC': {'games_played': 16, 'name': 'Chelsea FC', 'wins': 6}},
 {'Madrid Real': {'games_played': 11, 'name': 'Madrid Real', 'wins': 4}},
 {'Arsenal FC': {'games_played': 15, 'name': 'Arsenal FC', 'wins': 4}}]
```

**Explanation:**

`x[1]` is the value for each dictionary item you're iterating over. By adding a `-`, we can sort from largest to smallest, and if you want to sort by more than one criterion, just use a tuple of sorting values.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation!